# Execute thymeleaf template from project directory

Tags: java, html, jar, jvm, thymeleaf

I created a library which, in combination with thymeleaf (without spring), deals with sending e-mails.
I add this library to my project dependencies and there is a problem - the library does not use the html template from the project's "resources / templates".
After a few tries, I found out that the template that is in the library's .jar is being used instead of this from project directory.
How can this be changed? Do you have a sample solution?
I want this library to take html template for email from resources/templates of project that is using it

Comment: do you use maven? can you post your maven file and the project structure?

Comment: Yes, I use a maven. The project correctly added by the library I created.
It is on the external libraries list. I implemented the library functions and everything works. Besides, I can't set html template to be used from the project and not from the library

Comment: How is your library's Thymeleaf [template resolver](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf#the-template-resolver) configured? For a library I would expect that it might be set up to look for templates in a (configuable) file system location, using a `FileTemplateResolver`, or perhaps configured to accept templates passed to it as strings `StringTemplateResolver`, or streamed to it... and so on.

Comment: Another question: It sounds like you have two different template files in two different resource folders (project and library) - but with the same file name. Is that correct - and if so, why is that (just for clarification)?

Comment: Right now is using `ClassLoaderTemplateResolver`, so it looks like first I need to change resolver. Project that is using this library is stored in github, deployed on azure, in cloud.
I have got templates in 2 different resources (app/library) because in act of desperation I added it to library.
So I will change resolver to FileTemplateResolver and then hmm... Add some prefix to use project root directory? I think it will affect only library directory, not project. Hmmm

Comment: I tried with `FileTemplateResolver` but this one need to point at local template (full address to file on local disk).

Answer (score 1):

I also have this setup locking as following:

```
pom.xml
- src
|- main
  |- java/main
     Src.java
  |- resources
     template.html
```

and the code where the template is loaded:

```
protected static String generateHtml(Data data) {
    final ClassLoaderTemplateResolver templateResolver = new ClassLoaderTemplateResolver();
    templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
    templateResolver.setTemplateMode("HTML");
    
    final TemplateEngine templateEngine = new TemplateEngine();
    templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver);
    
    final Context context = new Context();
    context.setVariable("someData", data.getSomeData());
    
    final String html = templateEngine.process("template", context);
    return html;
}
```

do you have also the same structure? This worked for me...

Comment: Your solution will work if thymeleaf is added directly to the project as a dependency.
For me it is packed in the library.
I have a library called "email-sender", this library has thymeleaf in its dependence. The library is packed into a jar.
Then this library dependency is added to my project, the "student-management-app."

Answer (score 0):

Maybe host template somewhere and use url template resolver? There is no other option

Comment: Instead of adding "this should work..." as answers provide detailed answers that will actually provide an answer to the question.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, but I think there should be a way to force the template to load from project resources in a different way than hosting the template

Comment: No, by default it takes template from directory where thymeleaf is added to dependencies. When u use thymeleaf wrapped by ur library - its going to takes from library resources